# Get minimum of SortedKeyList with a condition on an object attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sortedcontainers

I have a `SortedKeyList` of objects sorted by timestamp, the objects also have another attribute, the ID.

I was trying to get the earliest element of the list based on the ID.

This is a code example:

```
import numpy as np
import sortedcontainers

class Point:
    def __init__(self, timestamp, id):
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.id = id

point_list = sortedcontainers.SortedKeyList(key=lambda x: x.timestamp)

point_list.add(Point(np.datetime64("2021-07-05T09:00:00"), "B"))
point_list.add(Point(np.datetime64("2021-07-05T09:00:01"), "A"))
point_list.add(Point(np.datetime64("2021-07-05T09:00:03"), "A"))
point_list.add(Point(np.datetime64("2021-07-05T09:01:00"), "B"))
```

I would like to select on the ID and take the minimum.

For example I want the earliest point for `ID=A` and, in this case, is:

```
Point(np.datetime64("2021-07-05T09:00:01"), "A")
```

I was trying to do something like this:

```
min(point_list, key=lambda x: x.timestamp if(x.id=="A") else None).timestamp
```

but this give me a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'NoneType'
```

This is part of a bigger project, so I can refactor the part related to `SortedKeyList`, but I can't modify the object `Point`.

Any idea?

Comment: Don't use `None` as the 'default'

Comment: How about working with a new list, `[x for x in point_list if x.id=='A']`

Comment: Or when specifying `key`, use some late `np.datetime64` if not in 'A', so they a sorted last.  The point is that all values produced by the `key` expression have to be comparable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following @hpaulj I used a late `np.datetime64`:

```
min(point_list, key=lambda x: x.timestamp if(x.id=="A") else np.datetime64("now").astype("datetime64[ns]")).timestamp
```

as the time precision over the other timestamp is in nanoseconds, I am pretty confident that this should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

As the list is already sorted by `timestamp`, you need to iterate only until you see an item with the given `id`. This should be faster for the average case than using `min()`:

```
point_id = 'A'
min_point = None

for point in point_list:
    if point.id == point_id:
        min_point = point
        break
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
min_point = next((point for point in point_list if point.id == point_id), None)
```